# Providing a "safe" push() function for use with auto_ptr

Tags: c++, templates, auto-ptr

I want to declare a "safe" `push()` function for use with `auto_ptr` like this:

```
template<class StackType,typename T>
inline void push( StackType &s, auto_ptr<T> p ) {
  s.push( p.get() );
  p.release();
}
```

I also want it to work for null pointers, e.g.:

```
push( my_stack, 0 ); // push a null pointer
```

Hence, a specialization:

```
template<class StackType>
inline void push( StackType &s, int p ) {
  s.push( reinterpret_cast<typename StackType::value_type>( p ) );
}
```

While it works, it's both ugly and allows erroneous code like:

```
push( my_stack, 1 ); // ???
```

to compile.

How can I write a specialization of `push()` such that it accepts only `0` as a valid `int` value (for the null pointer)?

**Requirements**

- `StackType` is some stack-like container class that I *must* use and whose source code I can *not* change (just like `std::stack`).  I can assume it has a `push()` member function.
- I can not use `nullptr` since I can not require a C++0x compiler.

Comment: Will you know at compile-time that the pointer is null? i.e. will you have code like this?: `char * ptr = 0; push( my_stack, ptr );`

Comment: @Aaron: I will know at compile-time that the pointer is null, i.e., is the literal 0.

Comment: I don't have a good answer yet, but it's useful to have that clarified that it's a literal `0`. Would you be allowed to make your own clone of the `nullptr` type, and require users to pass in an instance of that type? `push (my_stack, my_null)`    And one more question: assuming it must be a literal `0`, would you be allowed to define `push` as a macro?

Comment: @Aaron: yes, I can define push as a macro, e.g., PUSH(stack,arg).

Comment: I've given up. But I'll tell you what I was thinking about. You might be able to use template specialization to distinguish a literal `0`from other literal ints.  `template <int i> struct MustBeZero;

template<>
struct MustBeZero<0> {
};

int main() {
        MustBeZero<0> m0; /* compiles OK */
        MustBeZero<1> m1; /* error: aggregate ‘MustBeZero<1> m1’ has incomplete type and cannot be defined */
} `

Answer (score 3):

You could overload the function as follows:

```
template<class StackType,typename T>
inline void push( StackType &s, auto_ptr<T> p ) {
  s.push( p.get() );
  p.release();
}

template<class StackType>
inline void push( StackType &s )
{
  s.push( reinterpret_cast<typename StackType::value_type>( 0 ) );
}
```

then use it:

```
push( my_stack );
push( my_stack, auto_ptr_var );
```

Comment: We were not given details on `s.push`, but I think `s.push(0)` is what was intended rather than the `reinterpret_cast` stuff. (e.g. the null pointer is mentioned in the question).

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: second iteration. (The first assumed that the `push` method of some particular stack class was to be overloaded.)

This iteration instead seeks to provide `push` as a function template for any class providing a push member that takes can store `T*`.  The intent is to allow `auto_ptr<T>` and `0` as arguments, but to disallow other integral values and pointers.

The basic trick is still the same: provide an overload such that `push(s, 0)` actually interprets `0` as a null pointer to member.

```
class X;

template<typename StackType, typename T>
void push(StackType& s, std::auto_ptr<T> p);

template<typename ST>
void push(ST&, int (X::*));

class X {
  private:
    int m;
    X(); // unimplemented
    X(const X&); // unimplemented
    X& operator=(const X&); // unimplemented
    ~X(); // unimplemented

   template<typename ST>
   friend
   void push(ST&, int (X::*));
};

template<typename StackType, typename T>
void push(StackType& s, std::auto_ptr<T> p) {
    s.push(p.get());
    p.release();
}

template<typename StackType>
void push(StackType& s, int (X::*)) {
    s.push(0);
}
```

Test:

```
std::stack<int*> s;
push(s, std::auto_ptr(new int(1))); // works
push(s, 0);  // works
push(s, 1);  // errors out: no matching function
```

Comment: Aside form being overkill, your implementation doesn't solve the problem.  Your line "stk.push_back(p.release());" is not exception safe: if the push_back() throws, p will leak.  The whole point is not to release until after push succeeds.

Comment: I wasn't trying to make it exception safe.  I was trying to show you how to overload a function so that it accepts NULL as the only bare pointer.  The only overkill is that I wanted a fully standalone example.

Comment: Okay, to be fair, I should say "accepts NULL as the only bare pointer **from non-`friend`s of `S`**"

Comment: But point taken.  Let me change it so that `push` doesn't leak if `push_back` throws...

Comment: Although not explicit in my original question, the assumption was that StackType is some other class whose source I can not modify.  All I know about it is that it has a push() member function.

Comment: Ah okay, sorry, didn't understand what the restrictions were.  Edited my solution to provide a non-member push that works with `auto_ptr` and `0` and nothing else.  (Obviously the intent here is to prevent accidental misuse, not a determined abuser)

Answer (score 0):

You need a specific null pointer type to handle this case. This is why C++11 brings in `nullptr`.

Comment: I'm aware of nullptr, but the code can't require a C++11 compiler.